# Specific search in notepad++ or similar text editor

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have a document with multiple lines and stuff and there's a lot of SQL tables, so I need to find everything that matches ***"FROM XXX001 WHERE"*** where XXX001 are different table names, so how can I replace that to search that expression no matter what's between the ***FROM*** and the ***WHERE***

Is there any way to do a search like this in Notepad++ or any similar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow this instructions:

1. Use this pattern: `FROM\s+\S+\s+WHERE`.

   - `\s+` means at least one space character
   - and `\S+` means at least one non-space character
2. Check `Regular Expression`.
3. Do your search.
4. Look the results.

Hope it helps.

[image]